# Generate URL client-side for jQuery Grid from json field?

Tags: jquery-ui, gridview, struts2

We are using Struts 2 and want a jQuery Grid showing a list of accounts.  When a user clicks an account we want to take them to a page specific to that account.

At this point I'm looking for suggestions as to the best way to do this.  Currently I'm building a URL server side which I then return but this isn't optimal since I don't have access to `<s:url>`.

One idea I've had is to combine `<s:url>` and each row Id on the client side but I haven't found a way to do this.  Is there a grid would that allow this? or a better way?

---

Updated Explanation Attempt:

I am returning a json list to jQuery grid.  One column in the grid is a url but I can't build that in the service level.  Instead I'd love to have a way to use `<s:url>` when my json results are returned.  Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You cannot use `<s:url>` client side.
  The Struts2-Tags get used serverside
  to generate the HTML, so there's
  basically no difference if you
  construct them yourself or let JSP
  construct the HTML.
- There's the struts2-jQuery Plugin and with it the jQuery grid plugin. Find out more about it here:
  https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/

If you know the actionName and have the ID in the list you're iterating over, you can just code the necessary link yourself (if the object in the list has a getter named getId()):

`<a href="http://host:port/webapp/actionName?id=<s:property value='id' />">`

Hope that helps, if not please show the code of the page and / or dredefine your question.

Comment: I don't want to build the url myself.  That's the whole point for using s:url.  I just want to know if there is a way to use it while returning a json result to a jQuery grid.

Comment: <s:url> does nothing else than concatenating http:// to your host, port, appcontext, path and action name. It does this server side. So the only way I could help you is if you posted your JSP code to find a way to integrate <s:url> into this. Client side, you could maybe make an AJAX call to return a small JSP fragment that contains only the <s:url> tag you need, but you seriously won't want to make one AJAX call per line in your table.

Comment: There is no jsp concern in his issue he is using a json result type.

Comment: If you're returning JSON, you cannot use <s:url>. <s:url> is a tag that can only be used if you use a view layer technology, and JSON only returns a string. So you HAVE to construct the URL. And what the heck is so hard about building the URL yourself?

Comment: Nothing wrong about building a URL but doesn't s:url help if you change your structure so that you don't have to go change all your urls manually?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a really straight forward way.  Here is the answer to "Struts2 URL buiilding in action for JSON" answered on the struts mailing list:

http://old.nabble.com/Struts2-URL-building-in-action-for-JSON.-td30487914.html

If you get a chance let me know how you implement this.